# Как очистить список WorkInfo в WorkManager, android?

Tags: android, kotlin

При использовании WorkManager я столкнулся с проблемой того, что статус операции не удаляется поле прочтения.

Вот инициализации операции

```
private fun saveCashCommandSchedule() {
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()
    val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<WorkSynchronizeCashSchedule>()
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork("send_cash_schedule", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, work)
}
```

Вот я подключая слушателя для отслеживания состояния операции

```
fun subscribeWorkScheduleCash(lifecycle: Lifecycle) {
    WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData("send_cash_schedule").observe({
        lifecycle
    }, { states ->
        states?.forEach {
            if (it != null && it.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                //TODO вот этой строки хотелось бы избежать
               // WorkManager.getInstance().pruneWork()
                loadData()
                return@observe
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Каждый раз, когда я подключаю слушателя, старый статус всплывает. Мне надо его как-то удалить.
Использование WorkManager.getInstance().pruneWork() не выход, так как он удаляет все статусы всех операций, которые завершили свою работу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать статусы.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял вашу проблему, все дело в подписке.
По докуметации, метод `getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData` подписывает вас на полный список статусов задачи.

> For a unique work name, you can retrieve WorkInfo objects for all matching WorkRequests using WorkManager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWork(String) or WorkManager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(String)

Вам нужно подписаться через `getWorkInfoByIdLiveData`, используя `work.id`

> For a specific WorkRequest, you can retrieve its WorkInfo by the WorkRequest id using WorkManager.getWorkInfoById(UUID) or WorkManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(UUID).

Тогда статусы будут приходить по одному. Как в примере:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation